# (Updated) Laravel PUT Method Not Working

Tags: php, json, laravel

- updated -  the JSON file would return but it will not change the billing date at all.
- **Reference 1**: The official documentation about [changing the billing date](https://reference.chargify.com/v1/subscriptions/update-subscription-calendar-billing-day-change).
- **Reference2**: their sample code in detail:

  ```
  <?php

  $request = new HttpRequest();
  $request->setUrl('https://domain.chargify.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId.json');
  $request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_PUT);

  $request->setHeaders(array(
    'authorization' => 'Basic YXBpa2V5Og==',
    'content-type' => 'application/json'
  ));

  $request->setBody('{"subscription":{"next_billing_at":"2028-12-15"}}');

  try {
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
  } catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
  }
  ```

My code in detail:

```
   public function changeYearlySubscriptionBillingDate(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();
    $subscriptionId = $user->subscription->subscription_id;
    $nextBilling = Carbon::now()->addYear();
    $hostname = env('CHARGIFY_HOSTNAME');

    $headers = [
        'authorization' => 'Basic ANIDIANDIAJIJCQ',
        'content-type' => 'application/json'
    ];

    $body = ["subscription" => ["next_billing_at" =>[ $nextBilling ]]];

    $config = [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'form_param' => $body
    ];

    $client = new Client($config);

    $res = $client->put("https://$hostname/subscriptions/$subscriptionId.json",
    ["json" => [
    [ "subscription" =>
        [ "next_billing_at" => $nextBilling ]
    ]
]
]);

    echo $res->getBody();
}
```

Comment: Trying my best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks everyone so much for helping me out.

I've been working on this problem for 2 days and it was supposed to be right to me. Eventually, it is their API that misled me.

the only thing we need to do, is simply change

```
'body' => "{\"subscription\":{\"next_billing_at\":\"$nextBilling\"}}"
```

added a few '\' s inside.

Thanks everyone for helping me out, have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

The url you are building is incorrect. There shouldn't be a `/` between `$subscription` and `.json`

Change

```
$res = $client->put("https://$hostname/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/.json",
```

to

```
$res = $client->put("https://$hostname/subscriptions/$subscriptionId.json",
```

**EDIT**

Try changing the logic to make Guzzle call like this.

```
$headers = [
    'authorization' => 'Basic ANIDIANDIAJIJCQ',
    'content-type' => 'application/json'
];

$body = ["subscription" => ["next_billing_at" =>[ $nextBilling ]]];

$client = new Client();

$res = $client->put("https://$hostname/subscriptions/$subscriptionId.json",
    [
         'headers' => $headers,
         'body' => json_encode($body)
    ]
);

echo $res->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: thank u, I updated the question, now it's simply not working (it would return the json file, but didn't change the subscription date at all). Can u have a look for me?

Comment: Unfortunately, although I got the JSON file back, the billing date is still the same. It might be the 'body''s problem since the JSON is sent back to us, I just can't say how.

Comment: Can you try to invoke the api from a REST client such as POSTMAN and see if it is working the way you expect?

Comment: I will have a try, also, when I use the ext-curl method on the documentation, it actually worked. It's just we can't use that method officially, but I think the documentation should be working fine.

Comment: I just realized for another function, they wrote the API wrong... It's so disappointing that they wrote their own API wrong. Now I'm trying to figure out if they write this one wrong too.